# What is the benefit to use oozie bundle?

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I didn't really get what's the benefit of using oozie bundle. For me it looks like just a collection of parameters the coordinators sharing, but no additional control. If you not hardcode those parameters here, than this is just a "gateway" or another view of the properties what you have to store in a property file or environment variable. I assume there's some value, I just didn't get it.

Answer (score 1):

From data pipeline application point of view, Oozie Bundle are useful to the developers/users for managing the application in certain scenarios. Here is snippet from Apache Oozie Documentation:

> Bundle is a higher-level oozie abstraction that will batch a set of coordinator applications. The user will be able to start/stop/suspend/resume/rerun in the bundle level resulting a better and easy operational control.
>
> More specifically, the oozie Bundle system allows the user to define and execute a bunch of coordinator applications often called a data pipeline. There is no explicit dependency among the coordinator applications in a bundle. However, a user could use the data dependency of coordinator applications to create an implicit data application pipeline.

Sourec: [Oozie Bundle Overview](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/BundleFunctionalSpec.html#a1._Bundle_Overview)